# Data from User inputting into a Form and sending data to Python Backend

Tags: reactjs, forms, flask

Problem:
I am attempting to process the data from a form the user enters in the React Frontend . I want to do some calculations on a variable, I am currently just want to print it out, eventually I would want to return information back to the React application, but I can't get this simple step to work.

My Attempt:
This is the snippet of the form I am using:

```
<form className="patient-form" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="variable" />
    <input type="submit" />
```

This is the Python Backend in which I want to use the variable:

```
from flask import Flask,request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['POST'])
def getVariable():
    variable = request.json["variable"]
    return {"variable": 'Backend variable' + variable}
```

I am also using a proxy in package.json in order for React and Flask to work simultaneously.

When I enter information from the form I get:

```
Cannot Post /. --> This is on localhost:3001
```

On the flask backend I get:

```
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.
```

So this would seem like I am using the wrong route, which route would I use for this to work?

I apologize if this is simple, as you can tell I am new to React and Flask.

I found this post: [How to send data from React to Flask then back to react and show output on DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62824117/how-to-send-data-from-react-to-flask-then-back-to-react-and-show-output-on-dom)

I am still not able to POST data to the flask backend from the frontend form, am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand: Form send to Reactjs and Flask simultaneously -> You want Flask to send data to Reactjs.

1. There are similar problems here: i) [How to get POSTed JSON in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001229/how-to-get-posted-json-in-flask), ii) [React frontend cannot POST to Flask backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487931/react-frontend-cannot-post-to-flask-backend/56488972) and iii) [Not able to post data from React Js to Node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986299/not-able-to-post-data-from-react-js-to-node-js)
2. Change the concept: From the form send the data to reactjs. Then send POST request with Axios to Flask to get back the calculated variables.

Example code:

````
```
const response = await axios.post(
  'https://example.com',
  { example: 'data' },
  { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
)
console.log(response.data)
```
````

where https://example.com use your flask server address.

Caution: If your flask server listens to different port (e.g. port 5000), you must use the address with the port in the form `address:port` (e.g. localhost:5000 or 127.0.0.1:5000 or https://example.com:5000).

More information about Axios, check this link: [How to send HTTP Requests in React | malcoded](https://malcoded.com/posts/react-http-requests-axios/) or try to understand the answers from the above links.

Comment: Would I need to put that inside of an async? I am having trouble understanding where to use this in my code

Comment: As i don't have an example of your ReactJS code, i assume that your code in ReactJS receive the data from your form. At the section where your code check the submitted data, you add there the above code.  `console.log(response.data)` is just an example to preview the received data from flask. Just learn more about how to make REST apps to understand more about what i proposed to you.

Answer (score 0):

Recieving Data from Frontend to Flask is pretty straight-forward

```
from flask import request

@app.route("/recieve_data", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def recieve_data():

    if request.method == "POST":

        data = request.get_data()

        data = json.loads(data)
        # Do Stuff Here
        return data
```

Sending Data to Frontend from Flask is usually done through jinja.

```
var data = JSON.parse("{{data|tojson}}")
```

Comment: Would this work if the input was from a form: I am doing `variable = request.form.get('Variable',None) return variable ` But I am still getting cannot Post error and Method Not allowed error on the backend